# If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2a_n)$ exist then show that $\sum a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2a_n)$ exist then show that $\sum a_n$ converges.

my try:We have to somehow use the fact that $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ converges but don't know how.

Comment: Would one of the Comparison Tests help?

Comment: Write the exact definition of the convergence of the sequence. If the limit is $l$. After a certain $N$ we know that $n^2a_n < l+1$, so $0 < a_n < \frac{1+l}{n^2}$, then use the Sum symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 |a_n|$.  We know this exists because $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 a_n$ exists.  Also $L \geq 0$.

Let $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$.  We know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges.  Moreover,
$$
    \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{1/n^2}
    = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 |a_n| = L
$$
So by the Limit Comparison Test $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges.

(The usual Limit Comparison Test requires $L>0$.  But it can be extended to: if $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 0$, and $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges.)

Answer (score 2):

Every convergent sequence is bounded. Hence,
$$
\sum|a_n|=\sum\frac{|n^2a_n|}{n^2}\le M\sum\frac1{n^2},
$$
where $M>0$ is such that $|n^2a_n|\le M$ for each $n\ge1$. Every absolutely convergent sequence converges. We conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Here you want to use the limit comparison test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test. This is a pretty straightforward example and yes you want to use that series $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges